How change the background color of the app in MAUI for iOS18
I have my .NET8 MAUI application with my logo. With the release of iOS 18, most of the icons can change the background colour based on the dark mode of the iPhone.

I was wondering if with MAUI it is possible to change the background of the app icon based on the setting of the phone or create the icon with transparent background.
